# Custom ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with Spring Boot Async

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot, threadpool

I have a Spring Boot application which is responsible for answering requests via REST. I also push metrics about my application call. Since this is a separate task and I have to response users immediately, I want to make that metrics publishing asynchronously. So I've used that:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyApp-");
executor.initialize();
return executor;
```

However, this one uses `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` and does not reuse any threads.

1) How can I use `ConcurrentTaskExecutor` instead of `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`?

2) Which implementation could best fit for my needs?

Comment: `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` does not use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, it uses Java's standard [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) (see the [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java)). So you are already sort of using the `ConcurrentTaskExecutor`.

Answer (score 10):

To make your custom Executor work, make sure it's registered as a Bean, and reference it on the method annotated with `@Async`:

```
@Bean(name = "transcodingPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor transcodingPoolTaskExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("transcoder-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

And in the `@Service` which is holding the method:

```
@Async("transcodingPoolTaskExecutor")
public void transcodeVideo(UUID fileId) {
    mediaFileService.transcodeVideo(fileId);
}
```

Comment: You should not call `executor.initialize()`, because it's called by Spring through `InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also redefine the default executor by creating a Configuration class which implements `AsyncConfigurer`. Something like this:

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Value("${async.executor.corePoolSize:20}")
    private int corePoolSize;

    @Value("${async.executor.maxPoolSize:100}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    @Value("${async.executor.queueCapacity:50}")
    private int queueCapacity;

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async Executor -");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

In this case you wouldn't need to specify the executor name in `@Async` annotation. Spring will take executor, which you defined in `AsyncConfig`.

It's very similar to the solution provided by yglodt, but in this case you don't need to specify the name of executor in every @Async annotation, so it removes potential misspelling in the executor name.